# Java is blocking all proxmox consoles. I can't add it to the site exception list

Tags: windows-7, java

I cannot run a Proxmox console on Windows 7, as Java keeps blocking the page.

The [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) for it is `https://proxmox.dis:8006` (`.dis` being our local domain name).

Typically I just need to add the site to the Java exception list and all Java applets on that website can run (which I like).

I've seen some reports on Proxmox forums that updating to the latest stable release solves the issue, but I do not have the authority to do that; really I'd just like to get it working on my computer.

Picture of Java controls:

[image]

None of the above work. Separately, in pairs, or all together. N.B.: the IP address is fake; I've put it in when actually testing with the real one.

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

How can I make Java stuff it and run what I want it to run?

Comment: Did you restart your browser after adding the exceptions?

Comment: I've restarted the whole machine a bunch of times, incl. after adding exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to make this work (Java build 1.8.0_31-b13, ProxMox version 3.1-21) by adding two urls to the block list:

```
https://proxmox.local:8006
https://proxmox.local
```

The first of course is the address used to access the proxmox server web UI, the second is the same, without the port number.

After I added the second URL, I was able to answer yes to all the questions and finally get TigerVNC to run.